# Changing page based on selection

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have a page with a list of options and a submit button and I want to re-direct to a different page when clicking on the button (based on the item selected from the list).

The list is an unordered list and I have used js to change the class to "active" on click, so I was playing with the idea of using this to achieve my goal (e.g. redirect to page 1 if option 1 has the *active* class, redirect to page 2 if option 2 has the "active" class", etc.), but I haven't quite figured out how.

My code looks something like this:

```
<form class="options">
    <ul>
        <li id="option1">Option 1</li>
        <li id="option2">Option 2</li>
        <li id="option3">Option 3</li>
        <li id="option4">Option 4</li>
    </ul>
    </form>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

There are actually many more options and I've CSS-styled them to be in a box with a fixed height and a scrollbar.

I have the following js as well:

```
$(function() {
$('.options li').on('click', function() {
    $('.options li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    })
});
```

I don't necessarily **have** to use the *active* class (or js) for the purpose of this (I just thought it's something I've already created, I might as well use it). What would you suggest?

**UPDATE**

I have written this jquery script:

```
$('#create').click(function() {
    if ($("#option1").hasClass("active")) {
        window.location="option1.php");
    }
    else if ($("#option2").hasClass("active")) {
        window.location ="option2.php");
    }
    //ecc.
});
```

It seemed clever to me, however it doesn't work haha
Could someone please help me understand what I got wrong?

Comment: Are you want make a redirect from select option after submit?

Comment: @Adhitya Precisely!

Comment: Do you want use with `<select><option>` ? If want I can give example to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I trying give an example with `<select>` option.
I changed html code like this:

```
  <select id="select-example">
  <option>Select Option</option>
  <option value="http://www.example.com">Option 1</option>
  <option value="http://www.example.com">Option 2</option>
  <option value="http://www.example.com">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <button class="submit">Submit</button>
```

Then this a `javascript` code for `function` redirect to page in value `option`
I'm using `onclick` in `button` like: `<button class="submit" onclick="redirect()">Submit</button>`
Then added a function calling from `onclick` like this

```
function redirect() {
  var selectbox = document.getElementById("select-example");
  var selectedValue = selectbox.options[selectbox.selectedIndex].value;
  window.location.href = selectedValue;
}
```

```js
function redirect() {
  var select = document.getElementById("select-example");
  var url = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

```html
<select id="select-example">
  <option>Select Option</option>
  <option value="http://www.example.com">Option 1</option>
  <option value="http://www.example.com">Option 2</option>
  <option value="http://www.example.com">Option 3</option>
</select>
<button class="submit" onclick="redirect()">Submit</button>
```

Then if using **jQuery**, here an example
I'm using `data-url` for calling `link` then redirect that
So will look like this

```
<option data-url="http://www.example.com">Option 1</option>
<option data-url="http://www.example.com">Option 2</option>
<option data-url="http://www.example.com">Option 3</option>
```

On this field, we don't need a `onclick` function in `button`.

```js
$('.submit').on('click', function() {
   var dataurl = $('option:selected').data('url');
   if(dataurl){
   window.location.href = dataurl;
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-example">
  <option>Select Option</option>
  <option data-url="http://www.example.com">Option 1</option>
  <option data-url="http://www.example.com">Option 2</option>
  <option data-url="http://www.example.com">Option 3</option>
</select>
<button class="submit">Submit</button>
```

## Updated

We found a solution with `$('.options').find('a.active').data('url');`
Need a `find` for finding a active class, then get in `data-url`.

Here is snippet,
Or https://jsfiddle.net/tgrchs1w/

```js
$('.options a').on('click', function() {
  $('.options a.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
$('button#button').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const a = $('.options').find('a.active').data('url');
  console.log(a);
});
```

```css
.options {
  width: 50%;
  height: 240px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.options a {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.options a:hover {
  background-color: #b7d7f0;
  color: black;
}

.options a.active {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="options" method="post">
  <div class="options">
    <a data-url="http://example.com/">Option 0</a>
    <a data-url="http://facebook.com/">Option 1</a>
    <a data-url="http://google.com/">Option 2</a>
    <a data-url="http://yahoo.com/">Option 3 </a>
  </div>
  <button id="button" class="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is really useful! I don't want to use "select" because I don't want a dropdown menu (this is kinda the look I'm going for: jsfiddle.net/mn609daf - e.g. a box with some options). I have changed my code and written a script (added to the original post), but it doesn't work, would you mind please having a look?

Comment: @Jerry https://jsfiddle.net/tgrchs1w/ this is a solution

Comment: Oh, that's very good, thanks! But when I replace the console log with `window.location.href = a;` it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Please using a `window.location = a;` , Try it